# How To Get Min Value of column when column type is text?

Tags: php, laravel

i have column called price  with text type of Table Called Products 
Min Method Doen't work :

```
Product::min('price')
```

price columns be like
5000
,
90
,
70

“I expect the output of Min to be 70, but the actual output is 5000”

and i think that because the price column is text type

Comment: show us  a snap of  database table

Comment: The price field should be decimal, not string. By the way, try casting the field to decimal.

Comment: is there any solution without changing the column to decimal cause the project is live with live data

Comment: There are two possible solutions:

1. You change the column type to integer (or better to double for decimal), then you can use min/max directly.

2. You use RAW query and cast the column value to unsigned: ```SELECT MIN(CAST(`price` AS UNSIGNED));```

Btw. Using text type for a price column is a bad db design!

Comment: @CodyKL  we trying to fix thing in database now thanks for solution it worked

Answer (score 2):

For casting, you can use laravel model member `$casts` in `Product` model,

```
protected $casts = [
   'price' => 'integer' // or float as per your values
];
```

And then check `Product::min("price")` value.

If you want to fetch it by query

```
$temp = Product::selectRaw("MIN(CAST(price AS UNSIGNED)) as price")->first();
echo $temp->price;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can execute direct SQL query by using type casting

```
$results = DB::select('select MIN(CAST(price AS SIGNED)) from tablename');
```

Comment: worked perfectly but how to get value of     ''" array:1 [▼
  0 => {#1597 ▼
    +"MIN(CAST(price AS SIGNED))": 90
  }
]"

Comment: @mohamed try to `print_r($results)` , you will see how to get the value

Answer (score 1):

Use just min function, min function will return you the min value.

```
$price = "5000 , 90 , 70";
$array = explode(',', $price);
echo(min($array));
```